# Extra white space on the x-axis in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have written this function (inspired by [this Learning R post](http://learnr.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/ggplot2-quick-heatmap-plotting/)) for displaying matrices:

```
library(ggplot2)

tile_matrix_plot <- function(M, breaks) {

M.m <- melt(M) 
base_size <- 9
p <- ggplot(M.m, aes(Var1, Var2)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill=value), colour="white", size=.2) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="blue", high="green") +
  theme_grey(base_size = base_size) +
  labs(x = "", y = "") +
  scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0,0), breaks=breaks) +
  scale_y_reverse(expand=c(0,0), breaks=breaks) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_text(size=base_size*.8, angle=90,
                                 hjust=0, colour="grey50"),
        panel.background = element_blank()) 

  return(p)
}
```

When I try to use it say like this

```
tile_matrix_plot(
 matrix(c(.7,.4,.05,.2,
          .4,.6,.05,.2,
          .05,.05,.1,.05,
          .2,.2,.05,.4), ncol=4),
 1:4)
```

I get extra white space at the end of the x-axis. Here is the example output [image: Example of the image].

How can I get rid of the extra white space in the x-axis? It seems that the x-axis always extends one point beyond what I specify in `scale_x_discrete` using the `breaks` argument.

Comment: Your x scale is continuous so use `scale_x_continuous()` to get result you need.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the problem. So I guess discrete scale is for factors?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `coord_cartesian` to get rid of the white space. I've also made two other changes to your function. First, the function plots matrix columns as graph rows and matrix rows as graph columns. I've changed this (by reversing `Var1` and `Var2` in the function) so that rows(columns) in the graph correspond to rows(columns) in the matrix. Second, I've eliminated the `breaks` argument to the function, since that can be set inside the function, based on the number of rows/columns in the matrix.

```
tile_matrix_plot <- function(M) {                         # breaks argument removed

  M.m <- melt(M) 
  base_size <- 9
  p <- ggplot(M.m, aes(Var2, Var1)) +                     # Reversed Var1 and Var2
    geom_tile(aes(fill=value), colour="white", size=.2) +
    scale_fill_gradient(low="blue", high="green") +
    theme_grey(base_size = base_size) +
    labs(x = "", y = "") +
    scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0,0), breaks=1:ncol(M)) +   # Set x-breaks here
    coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0.5, ncol(M)+0.5)) +           # To get rid of white space 
    scale_y_reverse(expand=c(0,0), breaks=1:nrow(M)) +    # Set y-breaks here
    theme(legend.position = "none",
          axis.ticks = element_blank(),
          axis.text = element_text(size=base_size*.8, angle=90,
                                   hjust=0, colour="grey50"),
          panel.background = element_blank()) 

  return(p)
}
```

I'm actually not sure why `ggplot2` adds the extra space on the right, but `coord_cartesian` removes it.

Comment: Thanks. The comment by Didzis Elferts to use `scale_x_continuous` fixed the problem. But `coord_cartesian` seems useful too. Also, thanks for pointing out the changes. I was mainly interested in symmetric matrices, so the order didn't matter. I guess yours is the correct way in general. The reason I passed `breaks` is that for large matrices, say 40x40, I don't want to show them all. So either the function has do be a bit more clever, or I have to pass what I want to be displayed every time.